# How can I replace the name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this PHP output:

```
$total.":".$newId;
```

When success the function live_update() echo response back. I need to split PHP output into $total & $newId and change the existing input name attribute to the $newId. To do this, I tried my best for hours but I didn't succeed. Any help will be highly appreciated. This is the live_update() function:

```
<script>
    function live_update(el) {
        var str = el.value ;
        var id  = el.id ;
        var name= el.name;
        
        if (str.length==0) { 
        document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML="";
        
        return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
      {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
        
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            var Resp = this.responseText;
            var SplitedId = id.split(".");  
          
            if(SplitedId[1] == "di")
            {
                var Fres = Resp.split(":");
                document.getElementsByName(name).name=Fres[1];
                var Total = Fres[0];
            }else{
                var Total = Resp;
            }
          
        
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML=Total;
        document.getElementsByName("coupon_row").style.disabled='none';
        
     }
    }
      
      xmlhttp.open("GET","profiles.php?act=live_update&u_key={u_key}&name="+name+"&id="+id+"&q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Would be a lot simpler if you used structured data and sent it as JSON.

Comment: I will still need to use JS to change the name attribute value. This must be done using JS because I don't want to refresh the page

Comment: Well one problem is using `getElementsByName` which doesn't return a single element but rather a Nodelist` . Why would you need to change the name anyway? That seems very unusual.

Comment: `id` is id of input which you need to change name ? If yes then you can do something like this `document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("name",Fres[1]);`

Comment: Where do you actually call `live_update()`? Looks like you already have an element reference and don't need to query dom again. Provide a [mcve] and better explanation of what you expect this code to do

Comment: It is a little bit complicated. The point is that I "have to" use different attributes for different roles other than their usual use. The id attribute carries the id and a key to PHP via live_update() function and looks something like this id="{id}.p" were {id} is a variable replaced with the DB table row id in the loop  and p stands for the price field needs to be changed. There are also id="{id}.q" q for quantity ...etc

Comment: Now, there is another function which duplicates table <tr> and I need to change the name attribute for the new <tr> to match the new record id returned by PHP ($newId). When PHP returns the total and the new ID I need to split them and get the new ID which JS in return should assign the new ID to the input name attribute. This is a dynamic process between HTML, JS and PHP. Maybe I'm wrong with this approach and maybe there is another simpler and better ways but I'm not a JS programmer so I'm trying my best and asking you for kind help. Thank you

Comment: There probably is a much cleaner way to do this but there isn't enough shown to know how to improve it. Changing name of form control element is highly unusual

Comment: could you provide a sample for "var Resp = this.responseText"

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
document.getElementsByName(name).name=Fres[1];
```

to

```
document.getElementsByName(name)[0].setAttribute('name', Fres[1]);
```

guessing that you want a way to change name of a single element. you can do as above.

if there are multiple elements with same name, simply iterate and change name with

```
el.setAttribute('name', Fres[1])
```

Hope it works!

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a Nodelist collection

Comment: How do you know it's the first one? You are guessing. I suspect OP just needs to do `el.name =Fres[1]` but changing name doesn't make much sense either

Comment: @charlietfl I think only thing OP is concerned about is getting name changed.
If there are many I've asked to use iterate over node list.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `setAttribute()` method to set a name to a HTML element. So, this is how it goes,

```
document.getElementsByName(name)[0].setAttribute("name", Fres[1]);
```

And `document.getElementsByName()` returns a list of elements so since you need the first element gotta use `[0]` index and set the name as shown. 
If you want to update the same element you passed in `live_update(el)` you can simply do this

```
el.setAttribute("name", Fres[1]);
```

Comment: You are completely guessing that OP wants the first one. How do we know there aren't more of them?

Comment: The question didn't mention multiple ones. If so, the person who asked the question would comment and I would suggest using a loop over the `setAttribute()` method to change it to whichever one's they want.

Comment: Well if there is only one then they already have the element reference as `el` since that's where `name` came from

Comment: Yeah, right. But what if they wanted to update a field with a completely new name they need to know that accessing using names might result in a list of elements instead of one. So I showed the long method I will now edit the post to update using `el` element if they wanted to update the same element they referenced